# How to use IP address in the search content source?

Tags: content, search, sharepoint

I have configured the alternate access for my Sharepoint site using the server IP address.

I need to use the server path as IP address in the search content source
(`http://10.104.55.333:100`) instead (`http://server:100`).

What configuration changes do I need to do?

I tried to use the IP address in the content source but it gives the error.

Comment: I don't think you need to add your site in content source with IP address. Sites having Default zone should be added to content source and it should work. Just try it and let us know result.

Comment: I tried it, But i am getting a problem. I am using web servies to get the search result. There i am getting the path as with the hostname (http://server:100) but i need like (http:10.101.130.33:2\100) because my application will not support hostname to communicate the SP server. It support only ip address.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopment/thread/19e9e7c8-f6e1-41f7-a066-e918eb097474 You will get issues while consuming WebService with IP address.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use IP addresses for searching for content as it leads to many issues, rather than using internal IP addresses just assign each with a host name that way if any IP's do happen to change for one reason or another your whole system doesn't go Kaboom!

If you are having problems with getting host names to work simply using the IP addresses isn't the solution and you should work out why the host names are not working you may be ignoring a problem and just making additional work for yourself.